# Curl is not working getting no result?

Tags: php, curl

I have been using a script with curl and it was working fine but since last day it is not working and I come to see this that the site on which I am using this that was first on http and now that got turned into https so I changed the http to https but got no success with it so if you people can please check this code that what is going wrong with it?

```
$userSearch = array();
$loginURL = "https://www.infamousgangsters.com/checkuser.php";
$referer = "https://www.infamousgangsters.com/index.php"; 
$agent = "OrgyBot (Checking list of users to see if they are dead)"; 
$postFields = array
(
    "username" => "d34dch3ck",
    "password" => "d34dch3ck93",
    "sublogin" => "+Login+"
); 


$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiejar'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiejar');

ob_start();
$output = curl_exec($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);

echo $output;
```

Comment: check for errors: `if ($output === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https isn't that simple with curl.  You need to configure it to accept the certificate.  Read more here: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/